# Help required in WinAvr programming

Tags: c, embedded, avr, winavr, avrdude

i am trying to run a source code of win avr  . after making the makefile when i try to send it using avrdude it is giving me error.

Please any one can help me

Comment: What error are you getting?  There are a multitude of errors that avrdude could be emitting, we cannot possibly help without more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the avrdude homepage for more information http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/avrdude/

Check that you are setting the correct part no, port and programmer when calling avrdude, eg:

```
avrdude -p m8 -c stk200 -P lpt1 ...etc
```

If you're using MFile to generate the Makefile, then these should be set for you. Open the generated Makefile using your editor and check the values of

```
MCU
AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER
AVRDUDE_PORT
```

Make sure they correspond to your microcontroller and programmer.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of better information on the actual error, here's a list of things to check when programming microcontrollers:

- Is the power supply correct?
- Is the oscillator running?
- Is reset correctly configured?
- Do you have proper bypass capacitors on the power pins of the target chip?
- Are the programming wires correctly connected?
- Are there any electrical conflicts on the programming lines?
- Is the avrdude powering it, or is the project self powered?
- What's the voltage at the pins on the microcontroller?  Is it correct?
- What's the overall circuit current draw?  If it's high or low, look for shorts and opens.
- Did you specify an erase command before a program command?
- Does the mass erase or blank command work?
- Can you see the programmer on the serial/usb/etc port?
- Have you swapped out the target chip?